# Redundant information in zipper data type in Data.Tree.Zipper?

Tags: haskell, tree, algebraic-data-types, zipper

In Data.Tree.Zipper the zipper data type for a rose tree is

```
data TreePos t a  = Loc
  { _content   :: t a        -- ^ The currently selected tree.
  , _before    :: Forest a
  , _after     :: Forest a
  , _parents   :: [(Forest a, a, Forest a)]
  } deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
```

Now it seems to me that the information in _after and _before is redundant as
it should show up in the _parents field as well. (The siblings of a node are the
children of its parents.)

Why is this? Out of convenience?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no redundant information. The `_parents` field contain the left and right siblings on the path from the focused tree to the root, but not the direct siblings.

Let's look at a concrete example:

```
                               1
                               |
                    -----------------------
                    |          |          |
                    2          10         11
                    |                     |
              -------------             -----
              |  |  |  |  |             |   |
              3  4  5  6  9             12  13
                       |
                     -----
                     |   |
                     7   8
```

This tree can be represented as follows:

```
t = Node 1 [ Node 2  [ Node 3 []
                     , Node 4 []
                     , Node 5 []
                     , Node 6 [ Node 7 []
                              , Node 8 []
                              ]
                     , Node 9 []
                     ]
           , Node 10 []
           , Node 11 [ Node 12 []
                     , Node 13 []
                     ]
           ]
```

Now let's descend to the subtree with label `6` (I'm using `fromJust` here as an exception because I know exactly what tree we're dealing with):

```
l = fromJust $ do
  node1 <- return (fromTree t)
  node2 <- childAt 0 node1
  node6 <- childAt 3 node2
  return node6
```

Now let's inspect the resulting location:

```
Loc
  { _content = F (Node 6 [ Node 7 []
                         , Node 8 []
                         ]
               )
  , _before  = [ Node 5 []
               , Node 4 []
               , Node 3 []
               ]
  , _after   = [ Node 9 []
               ]
  , _parents = [ ( []
                 , 2
                 , [ Node 10 [], 
                     Node 11 [ Node 12 [],
                               Node 13 []
                   ]
                 )
               , ( []
                 , 1
                 , []
                 )
               ]
  }
```

You can see that:

- `_contents` contains the selected subtree at label `6` as expected,
- `_before` contains the direct siblings to the left (in reverse order),
- `_after` contains the direct siblings to the right,
- `_parents` is a list containing two entries, because there are two levels above the
  selected tree, so it describes the path from the selected subtree to the top. The
  first entry says that we descended through label `2` which has no left siblings and
  two right siblings. The second entry says that the root has label `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the very thorough explanation!

The reason I was confused is that if you take the data type
for a rose tree

```
data Rose x = Rose x [Rose x]
```

and take the derivative

```
R = x L(R(x))
R' = L(R) + x L' R'
R' = L(R) / (1 - x L')
R' = L(R) / (1 - x L^2)
R' = L(R) * L(x L^2)
```

this directly translates to the following data type for the zipper

```
data TreePos t a  = Loc
  { _content   :: t a        -- ^ The currently selected tree.
  , _parents'  :: [(Forest a, a, Forest a)]
  } deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
```

where in this case, the first element in `_parents'` holds the 
information about the siblings of the focused node.
Obviously, both versions should be equivalent. 
I just carelessly assumed that `_parents` and `_parents'` would hold exactly the same
information. 
One small "drawback" to the implementation in Data.Tree.Zipper
though: as far as I can see the last element in `_parents` always
contains two empty lists and thus still some redundant information :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand your confusion, and you're right about the datatype not being as exact as possible.